# Game Center leaderboards shows No data available

Tags: ios, objective-c, game-center, leaderboard

I want the App to show all leaderboard when a user logs into the Game Center. I wrote the following code to do that, and it works OK until I once disconnected the network.

The App started without network, but local Game Center was logged in. When I reconnected the network and tapped to show leaderboards, it showed "No data available". I must terminate and reopen the App to make it work.

Oddly enough， if I added `setLeaderboardIdentifier` and did the same thing above, the specified leaderboard could be shown after network connected again.

Anything Wrong? Thanks

```
- (void)showGameCenter{

    GKGameCenterViewController *gameView = [[GKGameCenterViewController alloc] init];
    if(gameView != nil){
        gameView.gameCenterDelegate = self;

        [gameView setViewState:GKGameCenterViewControllerStateLeaderboards];
        [gameView setLeaderboardTimeScope:GKLeaderboardTimeScopeAllTime];
//        //[gameView setLeaderboardIdentifier:@"xxxxxxxxx"];

        [self presentViewController: gameView animated: YES completion:nil];
    }        
}
```